# Induced metric is a scalar for transformation from $x\to x'$? (Poisson E.A p.62)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I have a (simple) question about the induced metric $h_{ab}$.

In Poisson E.A. (a relativist toolkit) it says in p. 62 that the induced metric $$h_{ab}=g_{{\alpha}{\beta}} \frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^a} \frac{\partial x^{\beta}}{\partial y^b}$$ is a scalar under the transformation $x\to x'$ and a tensor under the transformation $y\to y'$.

If I wanted to verify that, how should I do that?

Comment: Hint: Use transformation property of $g_{\alpha\beta}$ and the chain rule.